# Caching properties using spring Cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, collections, spring-cache

I am trying to implement caching to my method using spring cache. The issue is that after first time this method is not getting executed, which means property is not getting loaded. If I remove @Cacheable annotation, it works fine. My requirement is whenever new property is added only then this method should run and load properties else it should return from cache.

```
 @Cacheable("mycache")
public Properties loadPropertyFile() throws Throwable {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        logger.debug("Loading properties.");
        if (this.locations != null) {

            for (Resource location : this.locations) {
                if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                    logger.info("Loading properties file from " + location);
                }
                try {
                    properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(location.getFilename());

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    if (this.ignoreResourceNotFound) {
                        if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                            logger.warn("Could not load properties from "
                                    + location + ": " + ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return properties;
}
```

XML File:

```
 <cache:annotation-driven />


<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
<property name="caches">
  <set>
    <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="mycache" />
  </set>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works correctly: the way you configured the `Cacheable` annotation it will actually never invalidate since there are no conditions to trigger eviction. In general, you can use the [`condition`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition) parameter and pass a SPeL expression to it, but it would still be impossible to check if the underlying file has changed and execute method body conditionally.

This implementation of "cache until changed" could not work since you don't know if *"new property is added"* until you've actually reloaded the file (or checked its size or timestamp, whatever).

If making the reload periodic is an acceptable alternative, you could try Apache Commons Configurations' [ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_reloading.html) or experiment with Spring's [`@Scheduled`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html).